# Why is the entity manager not null in the spring boot test parent but it is null in the repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, testing, spring-data-jpa

I've got the entity manager in the parent test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(
    properties = {
            "spring.profiles.active=test",
            "spring.config.name=app-test"})
public abstract class ViewerTestBase extends DbBuilderImpl {

@Autowired EntityManager em;
```

The entity manager here is OK. DbBuilder sets up test data. 
In the @repository it is null

```
@Repository public class PaymentTransactionDao {
@Autowired EntityManager em;
```

Causing the test case to fail.

The entity manager is mapped to the h2 database for tests.

The persistence config class is boiler plate

```
@Configration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder.dataSource(viewerDataSource())
            .packages("viewer.model")
            .persistenceUnit("viewer")
            .build();
    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
        EntityManagerFactory viewerEntityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(pspEntityManagerFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "viewer.dbo.datasource")
  public DataSource viewerDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "viewer.auth.datasource")
  public DataSource authDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
```

Setup with spring boot starter jpa

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web'
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2'
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-test-autoconfigure'
```

Comment: I am guessing that the classloader is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this through the use of constructor injection.

Change @Repository constructor

```
public class ViewItemDao {
  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager em;
  public ViewItemDao(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
  }
```

Change test. Note that the entity manager was being injected into the test classes with just @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and @SpringBootTest

```
@Test
public void testQueryId() throws InvalidSearchParameterException, SearchFailureException {
    generateTransaction("639051cc-4b19-4383-9c9a-89a80cd2a2f9");

    ViewItemDao viewItemDao = new ViewItemDao(em);
```

I did change @Autowired to @PersistenceContext without noticing a difference.

Comment: it's as if the repository is created by Spring in a context that is different from the context initialized in the test cases. i am sure there must be a more coherent solution to this with autowiring the repository class.... but i am seconding the above method as it works

Answer (score 2):

In order to put EntityManager within  persistence context, change:

```
@Autowired  
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

To

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

> A persistence context is a set of entity instances in which for any persistent entity identity there is a unique entity instance. Within the persistence context, the entity instances and their lifecycle is managed by a particular entity manager. The scope of this context can either be the transaction, or an extended unit of work.

[Official documentation hibernate definitions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/architecture.html)